# Error in parsing xml Response in react (nextjs)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, xml-to-json

I am working on a personal project and thought I would make a rest API that responds in json and xml both, everything on the json side works but when I get a response in xml. Everything fails and I get this error on console when I get the response and parsing it throws undefined.

**Error**

```
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: http://localhost:9000/xml/
Line Number 2, Column 1: xml:2:1
```

**Parsed response**

```
Object { message: "Success" }
​
message: "Success"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

**XML Response from the API**

```
<message>Success</message>
<result>
    <filmID>82396e66-116f-4cb6-b3c9-918fc8bbcd5c</filmID>
    <title>Thor: Ragnork</title>
    <director>Chris Dave</director>
    <released>2020</released>
    <stars>5</stars>
    <review>Lala</review>
    <img>https://i.ytimg.com/vi/v7MGUNV8MxU/maxresdefault.jpg</img>
    <createdAt>2022-07-17T07:10:31</createdAt>
    <updatedAt>2022-07-22T15:34:10</updatedAt>
</result>
<result>
    <filmID>4ef55054-2ec9-4610-8b79-da296939d3d3</filmID>
    <title>Thor: Love and Thunder</title>
    <director>Chris Shake</director>
    <released>2022</released>
    <stars>3.5</stars>
    <review>Okayish Movie</review>
    <img>https://cdn.theatlantic.com/thumbor/JW6HNa00mCHyTJv9OoV9GeHBlyE=/1x0:2220x1248/960x540/media/img/mt/2022/07/MCDTHLO_WD024/original.jpg</img>
    <createdAt>2022-07-25T12:58:50</createdAt>
    <updatedAt>2022-07-25T13:00:49</updatedAt>
</result>
```

I have tried libraries like `xml-to-json`.
How do I parse this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: From the API, I simple used a library to convert it and did `res.send(o2x({message, records})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've shown is not valid XML because there are multiple top-level nodes (they lack a common parent/root node).

However, if you are expecting this format, then you don't necessarily need a library: implementing your own custom parser is relatively straightforward using [`DOMParser.parseFromString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString):

> See also: [Parsing and serializing XML - Developer guides | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML)

```js
'use strict';

function parse (rawText) {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(`<root>${rawText}</root>`, 'text/xml');
  const data = {};

  const message = doc.querySelector('root > message')?.textContent;
  if (message) data.message = message;

  for (const resultNode of doc.querySelectorAll('root > result')) {
    const result = {};
    for (const childNode of resultNode.children) {
      const text = childNode.textContent;
      if (text) result[childNode.tagName] = text;
    }
    (data.results ??= []).push(result);
  }

  return data;
}

const rawResponseText = `<message>Success</message>
<result>
    <filmID>82396e66-116f-4cb6-b3c9-918fc8bbcd5c</filmID>
    <title>Thor: Ragnork</title>
    <director>Chris Dave</director>
    <released>2020</released>
    <stars>5</stars>
    <review>Lala</review>
    <img>https://i.ytimg.com/vi/v7MGUNV8MxU/maxresdefault.jpg</img>
    <createdAt>2022-07-17T07:10:31</createdAt>
    <updatedAt>2022-07-22T15:34:10</updatedAt>
</result>
<result>
    <filmID>4ef55054-2ec9-4610-8b79-da296939d3d3</filmID>
    <title>Thor: Love and Thunder</title>
    <director>Chris Shake</director>
    <released>2022</released>
    <stars>3.5</stars>
    <review>Okayish Movie</review>
    <img>https://cdn.theatlantic.com/thumbor/JW6HNa00mCHyTJv9OoV9GeHBlyE=/1x0:2220x1248/960x540/media/img/mt/2022/07/MCDTHLO_WD024/original.jpg</img>
    <createdAt>2022-07-25T12:58:50</createdAt>
    <updatedAt>2022-07-25T13:00:49</updatedAt>
</result>`;

const result = parse(rawResponseText);
console.log(result);
```